# Second checkbox click is ignored

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

The following code ignores the second checkbox click. Anybody knows why and how to solve? Set a breakpoint in the last line to see the checkbox is still checked...

```
private final static String CHECKBOXBUTTON_URL = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_Checkbox";
private final static String RESULT_IFRAME = "iframeResult";
private final static By CHECKBOX = By.xpath("/html/body/form/input[2]");

@Test
public void checkbox()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(200));

    driver.get(CHECKBOXBUTTON_URL);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(RESULT_IFRAME));

    driver.findElement(CHECKBOX).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(CHECKBOX));

    driver.findElement(CHECKBOX).click(); // this click is ignored

    driver.quit(); // break here; checkbox is still checked (but shouldn't)...
}
```

Comment: The click is not getting ignored in your code. I have put a Thread.sleep(10000) after the line "driver.findElement(CHECKBOX).click(); // this click is ignored" and I can see that the checkbox is getting clicked for the second time and it is getting unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ignored because of browser's animation time interval to display the check mark in the box.

```
driver.findElement(CHECKBOX).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(CHECKBOX));
//Something can be coded here    
driver.findElement(CHECKBOX).click(); // this click is ignored
```

You can choose any of the following two statements.

1. Add a hardwait of 1 or 2 seconds. Use `Thread.sleep(2000)` . This shall allow the  transitive animation to settle.
2. Use `isSelected()` method on the target checkbox, to determine if it is really selected or not. The method returns true if selected and false otherwise.

Comment: I also noticed this behavior with sleep. I also implemented an ExpectedCondition based on isSelected but behavior is still the same. (second click is ignored). Seems like a bug in EdgeDriver.

Comment: Well , when selenium commands fail to do the desired actions on some browsers, you can get down to javascript (**provided browser supports it**) to do things yourself. You can use .click and .checked in a conditional block to do the desired task.  `document.getElementById("target").checked;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care a couple of facts as follows :

- *FluentWait*: Instead of [**`FluentWait<WebDriver>`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) use [**`WebDriverWait()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html), the tailor made specialization of *FluentWait* that uses *WebDriver* instances, until and unless it's absolutely necessary.
- You need to configure *WebDriverWait* with a desired value interms of *timeOutInSeconds* e.g. 5, 10, 15 but not **0**.
- *pageLoadTimeout()*: Try to avoid configuring `pageLoadTimeout()` until and unless the *Test Specification* explicitly mentions about the same.
- Once you `switch()` to the desired frame instead of `ExpectedConditions` as `elementToBeSelected()` wait for `elementToBeClickable()` as follows :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='vehicle' and @value='Car']"))).click();
  ```
- Your optimized code block is as folllows:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Checkbox_Click {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_Checkbox");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframeResult"));
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='vehicle' and @value='Car']"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Browser_Snap_Second_Select]

Answer (score 0):

You can switch frame using index and move to second frame using it, then perfom action on checkbox.

```
private final static String CHECKBOXBUTTON_URL = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_Checkbox";
private final static By CHECKBOX = By.xpath("//input[@name='vehicle' and @value='Car']");

@Test
public void checkbox()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.switchTo().frame(1); 
    //   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframeResult"));
     WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='vehicle' and @value='Car']"));
    element.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(element));
    element.click();
}

    driver.quit(); // break here; checkbox is still checked (but shouldn't)...
}
```